# C# on button click API value to Lable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, desktop-application

I am trying to check if email is valid/invalid/unknown using GMASS API which sends "Status" as string value.

For example try these links:

Valid Email Response [URL](https://verify.gmass.co/verify?email=random@gmail.com&key=52D5D6DD-CD2B-4E5A-A76A-1667AEA3A6FC)

Invalid Email Response [URL](https://verify.gmass.co/verify?email=wrong-mail@gmail.com&key=52D5D6DD-CD2B-4E5A-A76A-1667AEA3A6FC)

Retrieve "Status" value from JSON and set in Lable on Button click, How to achieve that?

What I tried, Inside button this code:

```
textBox.Text = "random@gmail.com";
                HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
                async Task Main1(string[] args)
                {
                    string api = "https://verify.gmass.co/verify?email="+ textBox.Text + "&key=52D5D6DD-CD2B-4E5A-A76A-1667AEA3A6FC";
                    string response = await client1.GetStringAsync(api);
                    var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
                    label.Text = status.Status;
                }
```

What went wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested it in console app, was able to get status {invalid}

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string api = "https://verify.gmass.co/verify?email=" + textBox.Text + "&key=52D5D6DD-CD2B-4E5A-A76A-1667AEA3A6FC";
                    string response = client.GetStringAsync(api).Result;
                    var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
                    var x  = status.Status;
    
                }
```

for the async task you can do it like this
**Note**:It will take a little bit of time to get the result and update the label

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = await GetStatus(textBox1.Text);
    }
    public static async Task<string> GetStatus(string email)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string api = "https://verify.gmass.co/verify?email=" + email + "&key=52D5D6DD-CD2B-4E5A-A76A-1667AEA3A6FC";
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(api);
            var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
            return status.Status;

        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked and how can we achieve that using async await?

Comment: How to set the result in label.Text?

Comment: label.Text= GetStatus(textBox.Text).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: Have you tested it? Without async I got the results but label.Text not worked with above solution

Comment: you have to put this line in the button clicked event

Comment: Told you it worked without async also the function is kept outside of button click since it's public I'm not getting any error but result is not achieved for some reason.

Comment: sorry, I was updating my visual studio so couldn't reply, fixed the issue, it should work now, but you have to wait for a while for the label to update as it takes time to get the request fulfilled.

Comment: now it worked, replace ```await client.GetStringAsync(api)``` to ```await client.GetStringAsync(api).Result``` in second solution